# What is the best algorithm to sort an almost sorted books in a library

Tags: algorithm, sorting

If there is the library where all books are already sorted except only one book that is not stored in the place where it should be. Which algorithm that I should use to sort this library with shortest time spend?. Currently I think it would be merge sort with O(nlogn). Any algorithm faster than this?

Answer (score 2):

1. Find the location of the book (an index `i`) - linear scan
2. Sift all the books with index `j>i` one place to the right
3. Place the book in the newly free space

This is done in O(n) with only 2 passes on the data, and can be optimized to be done in one pass only, by combining step (1) and (2) to be done together.

**Also note:**

This is basically doing mergesort with two arrays, (but with O(1) additional space for this variant):

1. Original (sorted array)
2. New book (which is also sorted array, of size 1)

Since array (1) - Original is already sorted, you can skip the recursive calls in it, and just go right to the merge step of mergesort.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that it's almost sorted, then Insertion algorithm or even Bubble would be the best... actually merge wouldn't be the best since it will make too many order checks.

Look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LT5k9.gif) gif, it may help you :)